# Check if file changed on SVN repo

Tags: subversion

I need to perform some operation if a target file is changed in the SVN repo. How can I test it?

More specifically, I have a local version of a `doc.tex` file from which I generate a `doc.pdf` file that is not on the server. If my local version of `doc.tex` file is outdated I want to copy the `doc.pdf` file to `doc-old.pdf`, than update the `doc.tex`, generate the new `doc.pdf` file and, finally, compare the two pdfs.

The only step I miss is the checking for updates of the `doc.tex` file on server.

Comment: You can use `log` and `diff` http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html

Comment: @GAD3R Thank you. I've already red than man but I've not been able to find what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I adopted is:

```
if svn diff -r BASE:HEAD ./doc/guidelines/typesetter-guidelines.tex | grep -q ^
    then echo "Out of date"
    else echo "Updated"
fi
```

Is there any contraindication? Can I do better than this?

Comment: I don't know what that `svn` command outputs for an up-to-date or not up-to-date file, but wouldn't `grep -q ^` just return true for _any_ output that is not empty?

Comment: @Kusalananda Indeed if the files if up-to-date there will be no output.